# How to calculate cumulative sum until a threshold and reset it after the threshold is reached considering groups in pandas dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, vectorization, cumsum

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data={'trip':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
      'timestamps':[1235471761, 1235471763, 1235471765, 1235471767, 1235471770, 1235471772, 1235471776, 1235471779, 1235471780, 1235471789,1235471792,1235471793,1235471829,1235471833,1235471835,1235471838,1235471844,1235471847,1235471848,1235471852,1235471855,1235471859,1235471900,1235471904,1235471911,1235471913]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['TimeDistance'] = df.groupby('trip')['timestamps'].diff(1)
df
```

What I am looking for is to start from the first row(consider it as an origin) in the "TimeDistance" column and doing cumulative sum over its values and whenever this summation reach 10, restart the cumsum and  continue this procedure until the end of the trip (as you can see in this dataframe we have 3 trips in the "trip" column).
I want all the cumulative sum in a new column,lets say, "cumu" column.
Another important issue is that after reaching out threshold, the next row after threshold in the "cumu" column must be zero and the summation restart from this new origin again.

[image: I have added a picture of my desired output.]

Comment: It seems your highlighted `0` values should actually be the value from the `TimeDistance` column? Otherwise you are not aggregating those values.

Comment: @Nick  the rows "after" the highlighted 0 will be exactly the values from the TimeDistance column and I do not want to aggregate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right. You can use generator with `.send()`:

```py
def my_accumulate(maxval):
    val = 0
    yield
    while True:
        if val < maxval:
            val += yield val
        else:
            yield val
            val = 0


def fn(x):
    a = my_accumulate(10)
    next(a)
    x["cumu"] = [a.send(v) for v in x["TimeDistance"]]
    return x


df = df.groupby("trip").apply(fn)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    trip  timestamps  TimeDistance  cumu
0      1  1235471761           NaN   0.0
1      1  1235471763           2.0   2.0
2      1  1235471765           2.0   4.0
3      1  1235471767           2.0   6.0
4      1  1235471770           3.0   9.0
5      1  1235471772           2.0  11.0
6      1  1235471776           4.0   0.0
7      1  1235471779           3.0   3.0
8      1  1235471780           1.0   4.0
9      1  1235471789           9.0  13.0
10     1  1235471792           3.0   0.0
11     1  1235471793           1.0   1.0
12     2  1235471829           NaN   0.0
13     2  1235471833           4.0   4.0
14     2  1235471835           2.0   6.0
15     2  1235471838           3.0   9.0
16     2  1235471844           6.0  15.0
17     2  1235471847           3.0   0.0
18     2  1235471848           1.0   1.0
19     2  1235471852           4.0   5.0
20     2  1235471855           3.0   8.0
21     2  1235471859           4.0  12.0
22     3  1235471900           NaN   0.0
23     3  1235471904           4.0   4.0
24     3  1235471911           7.0  11.0
25     3  1235471913           2.0   0.0
```

---

Another solution:

```py
df = df.groupby("trip").apply(
    lambda x: x.assign(
        cumu=(
            val := 0,
            *(
                val := val + v if val < 10 else (val := 0)
                for v in x["TimeDistance"][1:]
            ),
        )
    ),
)
print(df)
```

Comment: thank you for your response. your first solution is great even with my real datafram with more 5 million rows. However, I could not run your second solution to compare it with the first one. I got this error: "invalid syntax" , "val := 0" and it is related to "colon symbol"

Comment: @Siavash For assignment operator := you need version of Python 3.8+

Comment: thank you so much for your help, so, I will update it.

Answer (score 1):

Andrej's answer is better, as mine is probably not as efficient, and it depends on the `df` being ordered by trip and the `TimeDistance` being `nan` as the first value of each trip.

```
cummulative_sum = 0
df['cumu'] = 0

for i in range(len(df)):
    if np.isnan(df.loc[i,'TimeDistance']) or cummulative_sum >= 10:
        cummulative_sum = 0
        df.loc[i, 'cumu'] = 0
    else:
        cummulative_sum += df.loc[i,'TimeDistance']
        df.loc[i, 'cumu'] = cummulative_sum
```

`print(df)` outputs:

```
    trip  timestamps  TimeDistance  cumu
0      1  1235471761           NaN     0
1      1  1235471763           2.0     2
2      1  1235471765           2.0     4
3      1  1235471767           2.0     6
4      1  1235471770           3.0     9
5      1  1235471772           2.0    11
6      1  1235471776           4.0     0
7      1  1235471779           3.0     3
8      1  1235471780           1.0     4
9      1  1235471789           9.0    13
10     1  1235471792           3.0     0
11     1  1235471793           1.0     1
12     2  1235471829           NaN     0
13     2  1235471833           4.0     4
14     2  1235471835           2.0     6
15     2  1235471838           3.0     9
16     2  1235471844           6.0    15
17     2  1235471847           3.0     0
18     2  1235471848           1.0     1
19     2  1235471852           4.0     5
20     2  1235471855           3.0     8
21     2  1235471859           4.0    12
22     3  1235471900           NaN     0
23     3  1235471904           4.0     4
24     3  1235471911           7.0    11
25     3  1235471913           2.0     0
```

Comment: As Nick stated in the comments, the current solution does not sums the value in the highlighted row

Comment: thank you for your response. It works correctly for the sample dataframe that I have provided in this question, however, unfortunately, for my real dataframe with more than 5 million rows does not work and it takes more than 1 hour to run.