# How to efficiently perform a conditional cumulative sum over groups with a reset based on a threshold in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a DataFrame with a 'group' column, a 'value' column, and a 'threshold' column, I need to perform a cumulative sum on 'value' within each 'group'.

However, the cumulative sum should reset every time it exceeds the 'threshold' specified for the group. The 'threshold' can vary for each group.

Here is an example DataFrame:

```
 import pandas as pd


data = {
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    'threshold': [50, 50, 50, 50, 70, 70, 70, 100, 100]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)   group  value  threshold
0     A     10         50
1     A     20         50
2     A     30         50
3     A     40         50
4     B     10         70
5     B     20         70
6     B     30         70
7     C     40        100
8     C     50        100 

  expected_df   group  value  threshold  cumsum_reset
0     A     10         50            10
1     A     20         50            30
2     A     30         50            30
3     A     40         50            40
4     B     10         70            10
5     B     20         70            30
6     B     30         70            60
7     C     40        100            40
8     C     50        100            90
```

The expected output should add a new column 'cumsum_reset' to the DataFrame, showing the cumulative sum which resets after crossing the threshold.

Can anyone suggest an efficient way to do this in pandas without iterating over each row explicitly?

Comment: Sample would be more illustrative if you showed values that exceeded the threshold in each group.

Comment: Related, except the threshold is constant and external to the dataframe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74104136/12846804 - https://stackoverflow.com/q/45964740/12846804

Comment: We can assume no value in 'value' is ever greater than its corresponding 'threshold'?

Comment: *showing the cumulative sum which resets after crossing the threshold.* By the way, in your example of expected output, the cumulative sum resets *before* crossing the threshold, so that it never exceeds it. Actually resetting *after* excceeding the threshold would translate into 10, 30, 60,  40 for group A. So, which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `groupby` and `apply` with a custom function:

```
import pandas as pd

def cumsum_reset(group: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
  threshold = group['threshold'].iloc[0]
  cumsum = 0
  reset_values = []
  for value in group['value']:
    cumsum += value
    if cumsum > threshold:
      cumsum = value
    reset_values.append(cumsum)
  return pd.Series(reset_values, index=group.index)

data = {
  'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
  'value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
  'threshold': [50, 50, 50, 50, 70, 70, 70, 100, 100]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['cumsum_reset'] = df.groupby('group', group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: cumsum_reset(g))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  group  value  threshold  cumsum_reset
0     A     10         50            10
1     A     20         50            30
2     A     30         50            30
3     A     40         50            40
4     B     10         70            10
5     B     20         70            30
6     B     30         70            60
7     C     40        100            40
8     C     50        100            90
```

Comment: For row index `2` shouldn't the `cumsum_reset` be `10` given the cumulative sum of `60` passed the threshold of `50` and should be reset?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) to speed up the computation, e.g.:

```py
import pandas as pd
from numba import njit

data = {
    "group": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C"],
    "value": [10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    "threshold": [50, 50, 50, 50, 70, 70, 70, 100, 100],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


@njit
def get_cumsum_reset_numba(values, threshold, out):
    current = 0
    for i, v in enumerate(values):
        if current + v > threshold:
            out[i] = current
            current = 0
        else:
            current += v
            out[i] = current


def get_cumsum_reset(g):
    g["cumsum_reset"] = 0
    values = g["value"].to_numpy()
    threshold = g["threshold"].iat[0]
    out = g["cumsum_reset"].to_numpy()
    get_cumsum_reset_numba(values, threshold, out)
    return g


df = df.groupby("group", group_keys=False).apply(get_cumsum_reset)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  group  value  threshold  cumsum_reset
0     A     10         50            10
1     A     20         50            30
2     A     30         50            30
3     A     40         50            40
4     B     10         70            10
5     B     20         70            30
6     B     30         70            60
7     C     40        100            40
8     C     50        100            90
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- pandas `apply` is [very slow and should be avoided whenever possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432583/12846804). Which is possible here.
- `Groupby` naturally induces a reset in `cumsum` when processing a new group. Hence it is just a matter of grouping, not only by `'group'`, but also by passing over the threshold.

Here is a way that doesn't use `apply`:

```py
# 1. Temporary column: first cumsum, grouped by 'group' only
df['cumsum_group'] = df.groupby(by='group')['value'].cumsum()

# 2. Temporary column: times the sum went over the threshold
df['dividend']     = df['cumsum_group'] // df['threshold']

# 3. Final cumsum by double groupby
df['cumsum_reset'] = df.groupby(by=['group','dividend'])['value'].cumsum()
df

  group  value  threshold  cumsum_group  dividend  cumsum_reset
0     A     10         50            10         0            10
1     A     20         50            30         0            30
2     A     30         50            60         1            30
3     A     40         50           100         2            40
4     B     10         70            10         0            10
5     B     20         70            30         0            30
6     B     30         70            60         0            60
7     C     40        100            40         0            40
8     C     50        100            90         0            90
```

Finally drop temporary columns:

```
df.drop(columns=['cumsum_group','dividend'], inplace=True)
```

All that can be summarized in this equivalent one-liner:

```py
df['cumsum_reset'] = df.groupby(by=[df['group'], 
                                    df.groupby(by='group')['value'].cumsum() // df['threshold']]
                               )['value'].cumsum()
```